# Mongoose - Filter by foreign property

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, filter, reference

Using mongoose, how can i filter a model by a foreign reference? For exemple:

```
const User = new Schema ({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    office: {
       type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: "Office"  
    }
})

const Office = new Schema ({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    abbreviation: { type: String, required: true}
})
```

I'am doing the query as following (get users with office abbreviation = CDC):

```
const getUserWithCDCOffice = async () => {
    const users = await User.find()
        .select('name')
        .populate({
            path: 'office',
            model: 'Office',
            match: {'abbreviation': 'CDC'},
            select: 'name'
        })
}
```

although, it is returning all users and the documents that doesn't match, it's filling the office property with null. That's not what i want.

Please, can anyone tell me how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to also select the `office` property. That's the requirement for it to be able to work. [See the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

So, the following snippet should help you.

```js
const getUserWithCDCOffice = async () => {
    const users = await User.find()
        .select('name office')
        .populate({
            path: 'office',
            model: 'Office',
            match: {
              abbreviation: 'CDC'
            },
            select: 'name',
        });
}
```

Alternative solution, if nothing worked, just do it by manual JavaScript, like the following snippet.

```js
const users = await User.find()
        .select('name office')
        .populate({
            path: 'office',
            select: 'name abbreviation'
         });

// Filter out the objects with manual JavaScript.
const CDCUsers = users.filter((user) => user.office.abbreviation === 'CDC');

// Send response.
res.status(200).json({
  status: 'success',
  data: CDCUsers,
});
```

Comment: i already tried that, but, still, it returns documents that doesn't match. When it doesn't match, it fills office property with null. I want it returns only users with cdc office abbreviation

Comment: Sorry. What about removing the quotations around `abbreviation`? I forgot that it will be literally parsed as a string, where it should be parsed as 'abbreviation'.

Comment: Same, unfortunately. I'm starting to think that populate function doens't support that. Maybe using another strategy. But i don't know how.

Comment: A different strategy could be made using manual JavaScript's `filter` array method to filter out the values. EDIT: I have edited my answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks for the answer. For now, i'll just do the javascript strategy. But i have to think about the database solution, considering big numbers of documents. Filtering in application (using javascript), will bring all the documents from database and, then, filter the condition. This will slow down the function.